# Как в Умном фильтре (catalog.smart.filter) вывести все разделы в корне каталога

Tags: битрикс

Сейчас на странице раздела каталога, например: `/catalog/tovary_so_skidkoy/`, в Умном фильтре выводятся подразделы в которых есть товары. Как сделать чтобы в корне каталога: `/catalog/` в Умном фильтре выводились все основные разделы каталога?

Ничего не нашел в документации и хотел попробовать решить через кастомизацию шаблона компонента bitrix.smart.filter, но не нашел шаблон отвечающий за вывод. Компонент подключен вот так:

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:catalog.smart.filter",
"",
Array(
    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
    "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
    "SECTION_ID" => $sectionID,
    "SECTION_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["section"],
    "FILTER_NAME" => $arParams["FILTER_NAME"],
    "PRICE_CODE" => $arParams["PRICE_CODE"],
    "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
    "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
    "CACHE_GROUPS" => $arParams["CACHE_GROUPS"],
    "SAVE_IN_SESSION" => "N",
    "XML_EXPORT" => "Y",
    "SECTION_TITLE" => "NAME",
    "SECTION_DESCRIPTION" => "DESCRIPTION",
    'HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE' => $arParams["HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE"],
    "TEMPLATE_THEME" => $arParams["TEMPLATE_THEME"],
    "SHOW_ALL_WO_SECTION" => "Y"
),
$component,
array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
);?>
```

Т.е. шаблон должен быть в папке `.default` компонента, но при редактировании шаблона ничего не происходит. Не могу понять какой шаблон используется в итоге и как определить.

Answer (score 1):

Шаблон находится в папке шаблона комплексного компонента — `templates/bitrix/catalog/{название шаблона каталога}/bitrix/catalog.smart.filter/.default.php`